# JavaFX padding of VBox with TitledPane

Tags: css, javafx, accordion, pane, vbox

Since I need to have multiple collapsible TitledPanes at once (which the default JavaFX Accordion does not support), I added some TitledPanes into a VBox. This works fine so far, but I realized that the width of the TitledPanes is 10px smaller than the width of the actual VBox.

Following FXML code:

```
<Pane prefHeight="700.0" prefWidth="1000.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.71" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
    <children>
        <VBox prefHeight="700.0" prefWidth="1000.0">
            <children>
                <TitledPane animated="false" text="Pane 1">
                    <content>
                        <AnchorPane prefHeight="300.0" />
                    </content>
                </TitledPane>
                <TitledPane animated="false" text="Pane 2">
                    <content>
                        <AnchorPane prefHeight="300.0" />
                    </content>
                </TitledPane>
            </children>
        </VBox>
    </children>
</Pane>
```

Which produces this (see the gap on the right):
[image: before]

After adding and adapting a css file, the layout looks like this:
[image: after]

The css code:

```
VBox {
    -fx-padding: 0 -11 0 -1;
}
```

For me, this solution works fine, however it seems like a poor workaround. I guess there needs to be a smarter solution?!

Thanks a lot in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *pane* is resized with the stage, but the width of the *VBox* does not exceed 1000px.
The width of the stage of your capture is approximately 1010px.

You should be able to dispense with the *Pane*:

```
<VBox xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.111" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
  <children>
      <TitledPane animated="false" text="Pane 1">
          <content>
              <AnchorPane prefHeight="300.0" />
          </content>
      </TitledPane>
      <TitledPane animated="false" text="Pane 2">
          <content>
              <AnchorPane prefHeight="300.0" />
          </content>
      </TitledPane>
  </children>
</VBox>
```

Or use *AnchorPane* to adjust the size of the vbox, if for some reason requires a panel above:

```
<AnchorPane xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.111" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
   <children>
        <VBox AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0">
            <children>
                <TitledPane animated="false" text="Pane 1">
                    <content>
                        <AnchorPane prefHeight="300.0" />
                    </content>
                </TitledPane>
                <TitledPane animated="false" text="Pane 2">
                    <content>
                        <AnchorPane prefHeight="300.0" />
                    </content>
                </TitledPane>
            </children>
        </VBox>
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

Comment: Thanks, that was it! ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @geh:

Resizing the stage to the scene solved the problem without the need of a css adjustment:

```
@Override
public void start( Stage stage ) throws Exception {
    Pane root = (Pane) FXMLLoader.load( getClass().getResource( "root.fxml" ) );
    Scene scene = new Scene( root );
    stage.setScene( scene );
    stage.setResizable( false );
    // the following solved it
    stage.sizeToScene();
    stage.setTitle( "JavaFx Test" );
    stage.show();
}
```

[image: after after]